# What exactly starts the clk during spi communications?

Tags: stm32, spi

According to section 28.9.1 (of RM0091), the spi communications are enabled when register 6 is active (SPE set to 1). According to the rm0091 guide, once the spi communications are active, and register 14 is set to 0 (receive only mode) then the clk pin should start up. But when I pause the debugger at that stage, I can see both those pins be in the correct setting, but sometimes the clock is on and sometimes it is not on. So what exactly starts the clk during spi communications?

I dont know if it matters, but I am connected in half duplex master mode to an spi compatible chip (ssc). I am using an stm32f042k6t6 chip on a nucleo board.

Comment: *sometimes the clock is on and sometimes it is not on* Clock is not static as long as the output register is not empty :) You're likely testing the clock pin state while you're transmitting data.

Comment: I am watching HAL_SPI_Receive time out because it is not getting a message from the slave chip. The slave chip is not sending a message because the master chip is not giving it a beat to send to (no clock). In other words, hal spi receive is not sending clock sometimes.

Comment: "But when I pause the debugger at that stage" - stopping CPU to debug communication interfaces does not generally work.

Comment: I see the same register setup if I use "if" statements and gpio triggers on the oscilloscope.

Comment: Looking at the hal manual, on page 453 at the top it states:
'
In Master unidirectional receive-only mode (MSTR =1, BIDIMODE=0, RXONLY=0) or bidirectional receive
mode (MSTR=1, BIDIMODE=1, BIDIOE=0), to ensure that the SPI does not initiate a new transfer the
following procedure has to be respected:
a. HAL_SPI_DeInit()
b. HAL_SPI_Init()
'

Though it doesnt say where that part of the code needs to go or why...

Making that change solves the communication issues (missing clock and double send) but then adds a delay to the system as hal needs to de-init and re-init.